# mogrify and returning with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to generate automaticatilly queries. I was thinking using executemany, but I need to use returning statement so I did:

```
def format_bind(cols, rows):
    return '(' + '), ('.join([', '.join(['%s'] * cols)] * rows) + ')'        

def insert_many(table, values, id_column):
                if not values:
                    return []

                keys = values[0].keys()
                conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='postgres'")
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            query = cursor.mogrify("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES {} RETURNING {}".format(table,
                                                                                         ', '.join(keys),
                                                                                         format_bind(len(keys), len(values)),
                                                                                         id_column),
                                   [tuple(v.values()) for v in values])
            cursor.execute(query)
            return [t[0] for t in (cursor.fetchall())]
```

The problem is when I execute it, I get: `error list index out of range` Can anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using a combination of Python string formatting and mogrify? http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters

Comment: Just passing column names, etc. Not variables. Nevertheless, I was following a posting (see my other comments bellow)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that I thought I had to put an string parameter interpolation for every value to insert. I'll explain it:

Let's say I have a list with 2 dictionaries (with length of three) with the data to insert:

```
lst = [{'a': 21, 'b': 9, 'c': 33}, {'a': 76, 'b': 84, 'c': 46}]
```

In order to insert those values I did something similar to:

```
query = curs.mogrify("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES {} RETURNING {}".format(
                        table,
                        ', '.join(lst[0].keys()),
                        ', '.join(['%s'] * len(lst[0].values())),
                        'id'
                    ), [tuple(v.values()) for v in lst])
```

appending a total of three `'%s'` (one for every item in a single dict in `lst`). The result for this is the exception message **`error list index out of range`** and this happens because `curs.mogrify()` is expecting just **one `'%s'` for every dict in `lst`**, so for this case it only needs two `'%s'` instead three.

Therefore, the correct form to insert data from `lst` is:

```
query = curs.mogrify("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES {} RETURNING {}".format(
                            table,
                            ', '.join(lst[0].keys()),
                            ', '.join(['%s'] * len(lst)),
                            'id'
                        ), [tuple(v.values()) for v in lst])
```

Replacing **`len(lst[0].values())`** by **`len(lst)`**.

This how I solved my problem (I did not understand this because I did not read the code of the example properly). I hope this helps.

Sam

Comment: eh just to add on something which i overlooked as well - the `%s` following `VALUES` are not enclosed in parentheses when using mogrify